# Python: How to parse a SOAP request?

Tags: python, python-3.x, soap, xml.etree

I have the following SOAP request

```
<env:Envelope
    xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <env:Header/>
    <env:Body>
        <ns2:authenticateUserResponse
            xmlns:ns2="http://www.orionhealth.com/com.orchestral.portal.webservice.api_7_2.user/">
            <ns2:return>
                <ns2:authenticated>true</ns2:authenticated>
                <ns2:authoritativeUserId>fusion.support</ns2:authoritativeUserId>
            </ns2:return>
        </ns2:authenticateUserResponse>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

However for the life of me, I can't see to parse it

```
root = ET.fromstring(string_above_here)
    prefix_map = {
        "env": "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope",
        "ns2": "http://www.orionhealth.com/com.orchestral.portal.webservice.api_7_2.user/",
        }
    return jsonify(root.findall(".//env:Envelope/env:Body/ns2:authenticateUserResponse/ns2:return/ns2:authenticated",prefix_map))
```

How would I return the value of `authenticated`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seem to have done the trick

```
root = ET.fromstring(rhapsody.authenticate_user(u,p))
prefix_map = {
    "env": "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope",
    "ns2": "http://www.orionhealth.com/com.orchestral.portal.webservice.api_7_2.user/",
    }

if root.find(".//env:Text",prefix_map) is None:
    return root.find(".//ns2:authenticated",prefix_map).text
else:
    return root.find(".//env:Text",prefix_map).text
```